# UIWebView inside Navigation Controller crashes when typing

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, nsnull

I've spent a few hours searching for a solution to this problem but I can't even seem to find anyone who's experienced it, let alone a solution.

In my project, I have a main view controller that pushes a second view controller containing a UIWebView. Both view controllers are embedded in a navigation controller. The push segue and WebView are both hooked up using IB.

The segue happens as expected and the web page loads and works fine until I try to type. Tapping on a text field brings up the keyboard, but the first key press crashes the app and gives the error:

```
-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1899068
2014-02-06 04:37:19.550 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1899068'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0174d5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014d08b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
...
```

This happens both in the Simulator and on device. I'm particularly confused because I'm not doing anything remotely complex. In the view controller that contains the WebView, I have the following viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

and no other code. Google is used as an example site here, but it happens on every site I've tried. The weird thing is that if I remove the segue and present the Web View without the parent Navigation Controller, everything works fine, so it seems like the nav controller has something to do with it. As I said, the webView property is hooked up as an IB outlet. I've also tried adding it programatically, but the outcome was the same. As far as I can tell nothing in my first view controller should have any effect on this; like I said it's a Storyboard segue from a button. I can be sure sending length to NSNull is not anything I'm doing directly by myself, as I don't use the length selector anywhere in my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

It was requested so the full error message is as follows:

```
-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1899068
2014-02-06 05:18:29.607 AppName[859:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1899068'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0174d5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014d08b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017ea903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0173d90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0173d4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x016cd95c CFStringGetLength + 140
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x016e1284 CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale + 52
    7   Foundation                          0x010db634 -[NSString compare:options:range:locale:] + 175
    8   Foundation                          0x010db580 -[NSString compare:options:range:] + 69
    9   Foundation                          0x010eda59 -[NSString caseInsensitiveCompare:] + 80
    10  UIKit                               0x00454f48 -[UIPhysicalKeyboardEvent _matchesKeyCommand:] + 280
    11  UIKit                               0x00398ac9 -[UIResponder(Internal) _keyCommandForEvent:] + 312
    12  UIKit                               0x00398b3b -[UIResponder(Internal) _keyCommandForEvent:] + 426
    13  UIKit                               0x00398b3b -[UIResponder(Internal) _keyCommandForEvent:] + 426
    14  UIKit                               0x00398b3b -[UIResponder(Internal) _keyCommandForEvent:] + 426
    15  UIKit                               0x00398b3b -[UIResponder(Internal) _keyCommandForEvent:] + 426
    16  UIKit                               0x00398b3b -[UIResponder(Internal) _keyCommandForEvent:] + 426
    17  UIKit                               0x00398b3b -[UIResponder(Internal) _keyCommandForEvent:] + 426
    18  UIKit                               0x00398b3b -[UIResponder(Internal) _keyCommandForEvent:] + 426
    19  UIKit                               0x00398b3b -[UIResponder(Internal) _keyCommandForEvent:] + 426
    20  UIKit                               0x00252176 -[UIApplication handleKeyHIDEvent:] + 226
    21  UIKit                               0x0023a07c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2954
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x016d683f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x016d61cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x016f329e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x016f2ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x016f28db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x036f29e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x036f2809 GSEventRun + 104
    29  UIKit                               0x0023ed3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    30  AppName                             0x00003d3d main + 141
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d8b70d start + 1
    32  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: did you try to add a break point for all the exceptions? and if still can't figure out, maybe paste all the codes around the stop point. That might be easier for us to help you.

Comment: @XuYin I just tried that and I think the problem is coming from within a framework? All of the code displayed after breaking is a load of assembly. I'm definitely not sending length myself anywhere in my code.

Comment: Would you mind to paste the entire error message?

Comment: @XuYin I added it to the bottom of my question

Comment: Hmm, i tried exactly same code,didn't crash for me. do you have anything else besides the webview? when you say type in a text field, is that another control you have on the view controller, or just the search box on google web page ?

Comment: Just the webview, nothing else. And yeah I mean the Google search bar or any text field on a web page.

Comment: can you share your project, put on dropbox and share link.

Comment: What line of code does it crash on? Have you add an exception breakpoint?

Comment: @Popeye That's the thing, it doesn't crash on any of *my* code, the bottom of the stack trace is main.m then anything higher than that is assembly. The precise line it crashes on with the exception breakpoint is 

    0x23dd3b:  xorl   %eax, %eax

Comment: It's got to crash someone on your code otherwise it will be a huge error in Apples code and I very much don't think that is the case. Have you add an exception breakpoint in? Where does it crash when you add that in?

Comment: I think I might have been misreading the list of threads as a stack trace, nevertheless the error does not seem to be originating from my code. I'll grab a screenshot of what happens when it crashes to clear things up.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/rc2zDAa.png
http://i.imgur.com/rK1tvVt.png
Apologies if I'm missing something really obvious debugging wise. I'm still not very familiar with what Xcode has to offer for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to fix this by not really doing anything. What eventually fixed it was deleting the Navigation Controller that all the VCs were embedded in, then embedding them back in a Nav Controller. Now it works completely. So I don't know if it was an errant setting or what.

Comment: I have a tabbarcontroller at the root and 3 navcontrollres with tableviewcontrollers in them.  I removed the navcontroller from the first tableviewcontroller and re-added it and that didn't change anything.  I added a new tableviewcontroller in a new navcontroller to the tabbarcontroller and still.  It seems to be an issue of the storyboard file and not particular scenes or controllers.  Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

@deergomoo sorry for my first answer. I wash it as false.

So, what do you think about next example? Is it similar to your project structure? I can't find crashes.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UINavigationController *navController=[UINavigationController new];
    ViewController *viewController=[[ViewController alloc] init];
    [navController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

-  (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds
                                                          style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                   reuseIdentifier:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell";
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath");
    UIViewController *viewController = [UIViewController new];
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [viewController.view addSubview:webView];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:request];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:TRUE];
}

@end
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an issue with the page not being loaded. Waiting until webViewDidFinishLoad: fires does not stop the crash. Conversely, presenting the Web View when it's not in a navigation controller does not crash even when the page has not finished loading. Thank you for your time though.